# PyCharm Docker integration - 'No such file or directory' error when trying to Run from Windows PyCharm on Linux Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I have set up Docker on my Windows 10 (company) laptop, and now I would like to run the stuff that I code, inside PyCharm. However, I have gone through many setup and problem solving topics on web (including this site), but can't see any issue with my Docker / PyCharm configuration.

Daemon is enbled on Docker side.
I have created new Interpreter under my PyCharm project and set it to "Docker for Windows". In

- **path mappings**, I have added path where are the files of the project stored (which is mapped into docker volume in `*.yml` file).
- **Virtual machine** path is the path where are the files in Docker filesystem (I can access them when I open Docker console).
  **Local path** is where the (project) files are on my Windows machine.
  Connection to Docker seems working, because PyCharm does load the enviroment info, (python version and packages).

In project, I have set interpreter to "Remote Python Docker bla bla bla .."

In "Run/Debug Configuration" I have set:

- **Script path:** Windows machine path to script that I want to run
- **Project** was pre set.
- **Python Interpreter:** "Remote Python Docker bla bla bla .."  (the one I set up above)
- **Working directory:** Path to the directory, where the script I want to run is, in the Docker filesystem
- **Path mapping:** Local path: The path of the project files on my Windows machine | Remote path: The path of the project files on Docker filesystem.

And thats pretty much it. I have been trying different paths mapping. Also, I have had error: "Error running 'hello_w': Cannot run the remote Python interpreter: the working directory 'C:' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path" But that one I have solved by changing Windows path in "Working directory" under "Run/Debug Configuration" to a Docker filesystem path.

When I open Docker command line, and run there the command that PyCharm says is running: `python3 -u <my_path>/hello_w.py`. It works. But when PyCharms runs it, it gets error:

```
c3cdf3a9875d:python3 -u /<path>/hello_w.py
python3: can't open file '/<path>/hello_w.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Can please anybody give me some hint, about what I am doing wrong? I do python devel on linux for few years already, but I am completely new to Windows environment and Docker too. :)